# ORA-00917: missing comma error INSERT

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Below is the c# code I'm using to try to insert items into an oracle database.  I get the missing comma error, but I'm not missing any.

```
string queryString = @"INSERT INTO MAILLIST (GRPID, FNAME, MI, LNAME, ADDR1, ADDR2, CITY, STATE,";
queryString += @" ZIP, ZIP4, DOB, SSN, STATUS, DATEADDTOLIST, GENDER, AGE, MEDIA, BANK_ACCT, PRODCODE,";
queryString += @" UNIQUESSN, ACCT_TYPE, ROUTING_NO, EMAIL)";
queryString += @" Values ('" + item.grpid + @"', '" + item.fname + @"', '" + item.mid_init + @"',";
queryString += @" '" + item.lname + @"', '" + item.addr1 + @"', '" + item.addr2 + @"',";
queryString += @" '" + item.city + @"', '" + item.state + @"', '" + item.zip_code + @"',";
queryString += @" '" + item.zip4 + @"', " + item.birth_date + @", '" + item.ssn + @"',";
queryString += @" '" + item.status + @"', " + item.date_added + @", '" + item.gender + @"',";
queryString += @" '" + item.age + @"', '" + item.media + @"', '" + item.bank_acct + @"',";
queryString += @" '" + item.prodcode + @"', '" + item.unique_ssn + "', '" + item.acct_type + @"',";
queryString += @" '" + item.routing_num + @"', '" + item.email + @"')";
```

When outputted, the query looks like

```
INSERT INTO MAILLIST (GRPID, FNAME, MI, LNAME, ADDR1, ADDR2, CITY, STATE, ZIP, ZIP4,
DOB, SSN, STATUS, DATEADDTOLIST, GENDER, AGE, MEDIA, BANK_ACCT, PRODCODE, UNIQUESSN,
ACCT_TYPE, ROUTING_NO, EMAIL) Values ('0001190', 'John', '', 'Smith', 'address', '',
'Oak Ridge', 'TN', '37830', '',
04/08/1985 12:00:00 AM, '000000000', 'A ',
07/20/2015 12:00:00 AM,
'M', 29, 'NICK', '0000000', '12345', '00000000', 'S', '000000000', '')
```

When I tried to insert the data using command.Parameters.Add() I got an error saying 'Not enough values'

```
string queryString = @"INSERT INTO MAILLIST (GRPID, FNAME, MI, LNAME, ADDR1, ADDR2, CITY, STATE,";
                queryString += @" ZIP, ZIP4, DOB, SSN, STATUS, DATEADDTOLIST, GENDER, AGE, MEDIA, BANK_ACCT, PRODCODE,";
                queryString += @" UNIQUESSN, ACCT_TYPE, ROUTING_NO, EMAIL)";
                queryString += @" VALUES (:GRPID, :FNAME, :MI, :LNAME, :ADDR1, :ADDR2, :CITY, :STATE";
                queryString += @" :ZIP, :ZIP4, :DOB, :SSN, :STATUS, :DATEADDTOLIST, :GENDER, :AGE, :MEDIA, :BANK_ACCT,";
                queryString += @" :PRODCODE, :UNIQUESSN, :ACCT_TYPE, :ROUTING_NO, :EMAIL)";

                Console.WriteLine(queryString);

                using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                    command.CommandText = queryString;

                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open();

                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("GRPID", item.grpid));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("FNAME", item.fname));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("MI", item.mid_init));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("LNAME", item.lname));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ADDR1", item.addr1));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ADDR2", item.addr2));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("CITY", item.city));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("STATE", item.state));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ZIP", item.zip_code));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ZIP4", item.zip4));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DOB", item.birth_date));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("SSN", item.ssn));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("STATUS", item.status));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DATEADDTOLIST", item.date_added));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("GENDER", item.gender));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AGE", item.age));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("MEDIA", item.media));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("BANK_ACCT", item.bank_acct));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("PRODCODE", item.prodcode));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("UNIQUESSN", item.unique_ssn));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ACCT_TYPE", item.acct_type));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ROUTING_NO", item.routing_num));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("EMAIL", item.email));

                        OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                        reader.Close();
```

Comment: Can you print QueryString to a debug output and show us the results? I notice item.BirthDate is not quoted, is this correct?

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection - you should use a prepared statement instead (which might also will also fix your syntax problem)

Comment: If any value contains a single apostrophe (`'`) then your entire SQL statement will fail.

Comment: When I put the dates in quotes it tells me that I don't have a valid month.

Comment: Add that to the question - it can be formatted there.

Comment: try with `'07/20/2015 12:00:00 AM'`  instead of `07/20/2015 12:00:00 AM`

Comment: You must enclose the date strings inside quotes for the SQL.  If you typed it at the terminal, that would be necessary — it is necessary in the program string.

Comment: With the parameter stuff, the query string needs to be somewhat different; it needs placeholders like `?` or `:1` or something similar (the rules in Oracle are not quite the same as the standard, but I'm not sure of the details of the differences).

Comment: Do the types of the properties of your `item` match the column types? Is for instance `item.birth_date` a DateTime?

Comment: Look at sttan's answer.  You are missing a comma after `:STATE`

Comment: Got it, thank you guys so much!!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you haven't handled the date correctly. It should be:

```
INSERT INTO maillist (grpid,
                      fname,
                      mi,
                      lname,
                      addr1,
                      addr2,
                      city,
                      state,
                      zip,
                      zip4,
                      dob,
                      ssn,
                      status,
                      dateaddtolist,
                      gender,
                      age,
                      media,
                      bank_acct,
                      prodcode,
                      uniquessn,
                      acct_type,
                      routing_no,
                      email)
VALUES      ('0001190',
             'John',
             '',
             'Smith',
             'address',
             '',
             'Oak Ridge',
             'TN',
             '37830',
             '',
             TO_DATE ('04/08/1985 12:00:00 AM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss am'), -- note the use of to_date!
             '000000000',
             'A ',
             TO_DATE ('07/20/2015 12:00:00 AM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss am'), -- note the use of to_date!
             'M',
             29,
             'NICK',
             '0000000',
             '12345',
             '00000000',
             'S',
             '000000000',
             '');
```

However, as suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name, you shouldn't be creating the insert statement like this - instead, you should be using bind variables.

Re. your bind variable aware version, it looks like you're missing a comma after the :STATE bind variable. I think it should be:

```
string queryString = @"INSERT INTO MAILLIST (GRPID, FNAME, MI, LNAME, ADDR1, ADDR2, CITY, STATE,";
                queryString += @" ZIP, ZIP4, DOB, SSN, STATUS, DATEADDTOLIST, GENDER, AGE, MEDIA, BANK_ACCT, PRODCODE,";
                queryString += @" UNIQUESSN, ACCT_TYPE, ROUTING_NO, EMAIL)";
                queryString += @" VALUES (:GRPID, :FNAME, :MI, :LNAME, :ADDR1, :ADDR2, :CITY, :STATE,";
                queryString += @" :ZIP, :ZIP4, :DOB, :SSN, :STATUS, :DATEADDTOLIST, :GENDER, :AGE, :MEDIA, :BANK_ACCT,";
                queryString += @" :PRODCODE, :UNIQUESSN, :ACCT_TYPE, :ROUTING_NO, :EMAIL)";
```

Comment: Haha, should have read @sstan's answer before looking into the bind variable issue. D'oh! Ah well.

Answer (score 2):

Stick to your parameter binding attempt.  You'll be better off moving forward.

Your latest `Not enough values` error seems to be because you have a comma missing between `:STATE` and `:ZIP`.